# Compare generic objects/object list with C#

Tags: c#, object, compare, equality

So I was wondering what is the best way to compare objects? In my case the object could be any primitive type but also a list of primitives. And in the second case I would have to compare them one by one. 
So far I have something like this:

```
private static bool EqualityCheck<TValue>(TValue value1, TValue value2)
{
    if (typeof(List<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue)))
    {
        // .. Compare if TValue is list<object>
    }
    else
    {
        // .. Compare normal object
    }
}
```

How can I do the comparison?

EDIT:

```
private static bool EqualityCheck(object a, object b)
{
    if (a is IEnumerable enumA && b is IEnumerable enumB)
        return enumA.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(enumB.Cast<object>());

    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

Comment: What is the best way to compare objects? You can consider implement IComparable interface.-

Comment: @Dari I know that, my question was referring to the actual comparison.  How to compare them. Also my class is static, hence can't extend IComparable.

Comment: Compare objects with Object.Equal(). Compare Lists with Object.SequenceEquals() because calling Equal on a List<T1> and a List<T1> will return true even though they might contain different items. You might need to put a constraint on your type parameter to define it as Object. Object type implements Equals.

Comment: @Dennis1679 Please check, I edited my post.